# 24 hour time regex for HTML 5

Tags: regex, html

Wanted to Inquire about the possible Regex expression for 24-hour time format in HTML 5 (HH:MM) .

**if possible, kindly tell the regex that can be used in the Pattern attribute of HTML 5**

The time is expected to be in 24-hour format (HH not more than 23).

Kind regards,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think this is a possible approach :

```
<input type="text" pattern="([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" id="24h"/>
<input type="text" pattern="([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}" id="24h"/>
```

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Check out this jsfiddle : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6gjt/)

Comment: Thank you .. saw it earlier but but did not work .. probably was missing a bracket .. :)  . Thank you though ..

Comment: @AbdulAli check my comments out

Comment: I would recommend you add some placeholder like: HH:MM, or some example.

Comment: @virtualLast Please provide a jsfiddle with this issue.

Comment: @raduflorescu I've removed my previous comment so that I do not confuse things - realised why the pattern matching was not working, I was not submitting the form via a normal submit process - appologies

Comment: If you want to force to have the format: HH:MM (eg. 00:00, 23:59)
Then, you could use something like this: 

/^([0-1]\d|20|21|22|23):[0-5]\d$/

Answer (score 20):

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}" />
```

it does allow invalid hour values: 24,25,26,27,28,29, if you want to be extra correct you can do it that way:

```
<input type="text" pattern="([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}" />
```

Comment: If talking about time, for sure I want the Extra Correct way, Thank you, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force to have the format **HH:MM** (e.g. 00:00, 23:59)

Then, you could use something like this:

```
/^([01]\d|20|21|22|23):[0-5]\d$/
```

Comment: Just a comment - `[0-1]` is basically just `[01]`

Comment: Thanks @HagaiWild. I just updated the Regex.

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter regex:

```
(?:[01]|2(?![4-9])){1}\d{1}:[0-5]{1}\d{1}
```

So in complete:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(?:[01]|2(?![4-9])){1}\d{1}:[0-5]{1}\d{1}" />
```

In the first non-capturing group ("(?:)") we match exactly one digit, either 0, 1 or 2 not followed by 4-9 (negative lookahead "(?!)"). Then me match one more digit, since it could be any of 0-9 we can go with \d shortcut. Then we match separator ":". Then one digit between 0-5 and one more between 0-9 (again with "\d").
If for some reason you need to match 24 hours as well (sometimes you do), then just adjust negative lookahead, e. g. "(?![5-9])".

Comment: You can make it even shorter by getting rid of the `{1}`, which has no effect at all.