# Regular Expression for HTML5 input type=time

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am trying to find a regular expression that plays nicely with the input type of 'time'.  I want to use the new HTML5 input type=time, because this form will mostly be accessed on a mobile device, so it would be nice if the user was presented with a time picker.

However, some browsers don't do anything special with that input type, so I still require a regular expression.

I've tried both these examples:

[Validating time-only input in asp.net MVC unobtrusive validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872493/validating-time-only-input-in-asp-net-mvc-unobtrusive-validation)

[24 hour time regex for HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772142/24-hour-time-regex-for-html-5)

They work when the input type=text, however they fail when I change it to time.

Thank you

**EDIT**

The regular expression should validate the time with AM/PM, however it doesn't matter if they enter in a leading 0 (03:00AM) or no minutes (3am).

Essentially it just needs to work with a time input:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Invalid Time." data-val-regex-pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$" name="StartTime" type="time" value="" />
```

This returns invalid time when using the chrome time picker.

Comment: What should the regular expression exactly achieve? What are YOU trying to achieve? it's not quite clear. Could you add some code for what you have so far?

Comment: The regex should make sure it's a valid time.  It should force them to enter am/pm, however it doesn't matter if they enter 03:00AM or 3am or 3:00am or if there's a space between the time and the period.

These two regex seem to work when the input type is "text", but not when it is set to "time".

 - ^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [aApP][mM]$
 - ^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$

Comment: Post what you have so far, input strings that should match and input string that shouldn't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so based on Armfoot's response, I decided to use Modernizr to achieve cross-browser time input support.  Like I mentioned in my question, the input type needs to be "time" for mobile purposes, because IMO the time picker improves user experience.

I'm not sure if this is the BEST approach, but here is what I did:

Here is the starting HTML for this particular form element:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="StartTime">Time Started</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-type="time" data-val="true" data-val-regex="Time is invalid" data-val-regex-pattern="^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[aApP][mM]\s*$" data-val-required="Start time is required" id="StartTime" name="StartTime" placeholder="Time Started"  value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StartTime" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

The initial type is set to "text", and the regular expression for validating the time is:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]\s*[aApP][mM]\s*$
```

I used the same expression from the link posted in my question, however I added "\s*" between the time and the AM/PM and also one afterwards, so the it doesn't matter how many spaces go between AM/PM or if the user accidentally adds a space afterwards.  The 0? also makes the leading 0 optional.

For JavaScript, I added:

```
//detect if time input is supported
if (Modernizr.inputtypes.time) {
    $('*[data-type="time"]').attr('type', 'time');
    $('*[data-type="time"]').removeAttr('data-val-regex');
    $('*[data-type="time"]').removeAttr('data-val-regex-pattern');
}
```

The Modernizr conditional statement checks if the input type "time" is supported by the browser.  If it is supported, it changes the type to "time", and removes the data-val-regex attributes since those are NOT supported for type="time".

This seems to work fine across all browsers and devices.  I've tested it on Chrome/Chrome Mobile/IE/Firefox/iPad (Safari).  The time pickers show up nicely on the iPad and the Nexus devices making this work well for mobile purposes.  The regex works properly on Firefox and IE where the time input doesn't get rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I have good and bad news...

The bad one is that you cannot use the `pattern` attribute in [**input** types different from *text, search, url, tel, email, and password*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

While this is valid:

```
 <input type="text" pattern="([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}"/>
```

This would not be:

```
<input type="time" pattern="([01]?[0-9]{1}|2[0-3]{1}):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}"/>
```

The **good news** is that you may not need to use any pattern in `type=time`, since it already [has a pattern of its own](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html):

> **type=time (HH:MM)**
>   - time value with no time zone in 24-hour military format.

### EDIT

I noticed your edit with the following code:

```
<input data-val="true"
 data-val-regex="Invalid Time."
 data-val-regex-pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$"
 name="StartTime" type="time" value="" />
```

I also noticed that people using [those data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956627/custom-regularexpressionattribute-missing-data-val-regex-pattern-for-client-side), they still use `type="text"`.
I assume that is the reason why it "returns invalid time when using the chrome time picker".

I haven't find any case where `type="time"` works with other patterns (even with `data-`), and it seems this answer already explained it:
[html5 time inputs shows 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13523302/1326147)

If you really need to have the AM and PM you can try  to use `type="text"` with the regex pattern and trigger the datepicker through Javascript.