# html5 input time with unlimited range of value

Tags: html

I'm searching something similar to the input tag with type="time", but i want to put in this field ilimited value.
For example: 48:45.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219691/regular-expression-for-html5-input-type-time

Comment: Thank you but, i'd like a field with time picker, like it ' s displayed by most Navigator.
It's important for me because this web app shoulb be responsive, and shoulb be use on smartphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for my situation is :[jquery time and duration picker](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html)